# Accessibility Testing using Pa11y 5 on a page with Popup / Overlay

Tags: javascript, pa11y

I have a page that I'm able to get accessibility test report from Pa11y 5 using actions.

When I click on a button on that specific page, I get a popup/overlay, I would like Pa11y to sniff that popup/overlay page and report on accessibility metrics, but currently Pa11y 5 is only able to provide me for the main parent page ignoring any reports on the html in the popup page? Is there a way to achieve this, tell Pa11y to switch to popup and sniff on that popup html and report that.

Popup/overlay contains div[role='dialog'] as it is a modal dialog made out of aria.

I'm using the latest Pa11y, hence I keep mentioning it as Pa11y 5. I have not used Pa11y4, so cannot comment if this works with Pa11y 4.

Any help/advise is sincerely appreciated.

**Update:**
As requested, below is my complete (relevant) part of the code

```
const PageOptions1 = {  
    timeout: 30000,
    userAgent: 'A11Y TESTS',
    actions: [
        'screen capture screenshots/001-DefaultView.png'                    
    ]
};
const PageOptions2 = {
    timeout: 35000, 
    userAgent: 'A11Y TESTS',
    rootElement: 'div[role="dialog"]',
    actions: [
        'click element button[data-automation-id="ccbutton"]',
        'wait for element div[role="dialog"] to be added',
        'screen capture screenshots/002-Popup.png',
        'click element i.fa-close',
        'screen capture screenshots/002-DefaultView.png'
    ]
};

async function runPa11y(navigateUrl) {
    try {
        const results = await Promise.all([
            pa11y(navigateUrl, PageOptions1),
            pa11y(navigateUrl, PageOptions2),           
        ]);

        LogResults(results);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error: " + error.message);
    }
}

runPa11y("Url to navigate");
```

Comment: I now also tried adding to my options json array which I pass on to the pally('url', options) function to restrict the testing onto a subset of the page.

example: rootElement: 'div[role="dialog"]'

But this too, did not work as expected.

my options will look like:
options = {
    timeout: 30000,
    rootElement: 'div[role="dialog"]',
    actions: [
             'action 1',
             'action 2'
    ]
};

Comment: Hi Nan! Could you please edit your question to add your full pa11y configuration? I need to see exactly what you've tried to be able to help you.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi hollsk, I have updated with my code, I don't have any external configuration. I'm running the test by calling 'node testaccessibility.js' and LogResults, logs to console at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Nan! When the screenshots are taken, do they look correct? Does the modal appear and disappear when it's supposed to?

Comment: Yes hollsk, the screenshots show the modal dialog and when i click the close (via action) it gets closed and i get the default view again. The flow works, except the report is generated for the whole main parent page, rather than what I wanted, which is for pa11y to focus its test only on the popup. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your updates! You're doing the right things and everything looks like it's working as expected.

Pa11y will perform *all* of the Actions before running your test, so it's opening the modal dialog, immediately closing it again, and then running the test without it.

Break `PageOptions2` into smaller units so that your last Action is the state you want to test against, and everything should be ok.

Comment: Fantastic tip @hollsk. With the below revised PageOptions2, i got it working as expected. 


`const PageOptions2 = {
    timeout: 35000, 
    userAgent: 'A11Y TESTS',
    rootElement: 'div[role="dialog"]',
    actions: [
        'click element button[data-automation-id="ccbutton"]',
        'screen capture screenshots/002-Popup.png'
    ]
};`

Thank you very much.